# Help understanding the characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 &2  &1 \\ 
2 & 2 &3 \\ 
1 & 1 &1 
\end{bmatrix}$$

I'm calculating the characteristic polynomial by the following:

$$P(x) = -x^3 + Tr(A)x^2 + \frac{1}{2}(a_{ij}a_{ji} -  a_{ii}a_{jj})x + \det(A)$$

Now when I calculate using matlab (using the `charpoly(A)` function) I get the following results:

```
Ans = 1    -4    -3    -1
```

This makes sense since, for second result ($-4$) you can calculate $2 + 3 + 4$ and for result $-1$ you can do by taking the determinant of this matrix, which is (1)

But I do not and cannot seem to figure out how they are calculating the $-3$ (in this case)? I know it has something to do with the $\frac{1}{2}(a_{ij}a_{ji} - a_{ii}a_{jj})$ but what would these elements be in this matrix in order to calculate the third result for this?

Comment: I think the easiest way to compute the polynomial is use the general formula $P(x)=\det(A-xI)$, in your case: $$P(x)=\det \begin{bmatrix}
1-x &2  &1 \\ 
2 & 2-x &3 \\ 
1 & 1 &1-x 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: @Dario The equation that I gave makes sense to me. The example that you gave does not. What would $x$ be in this case?

Comment: If you compute the determinant I wrote for $P(x)$ you obtain a polynomial, i.e $(1-x)(2-x)(1-x)+6+2-3(1-x)-4(1-x)-(2-x)$. After some expansions/factorizations you get the same thing given by your formula.

Comment: @Dario Thanks for the reply. The thing is, I'm writing an algorithm that calculates the characteristic polynomial so factorizing would not be an ideal solution, hence the method that I gave was the most optimal. I just cannot understand how they are calculating the -3 result

Comment: @user1326876 the benefit of using Dario's approach is that we obtain immediately that roots of characteristic polynomial are eigenvalues (tautology in standard definitions, I know), while in your approach it's far from obvious that roots of your characteristic polynomial have something to do with eigenvalues and eigenvectors at all.

Comment: @user1326876 In the third term there is an implicit double summation: so in order to compute that you have to double sum on $i$ and $j$ from 1 to 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Dario suggested,easiest way to compute characteristic polynomial is to use det$(xI-A)=0$

But if you really wants to compute in a different way, the formula I know (from [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial) link in Wikipedia) is:

$p(x)=x^3-Tr(A)+\frac12 (Tr(A)^2-Tr(A^2))-det(A)$

And you can see $(Tr(A)^2-Tr(A^2))=16-22=-6$ (Please compute diagonal elements of $A^2$ only,you don't need to calculate $A^2$ completely)

So $\frac12 (Tr(A)^2-Tr(A^2))=-3$

Comment: What an elegant solution to this problem :) Although, I do not know what you mean by "Compute diagonal elements of $A^2$) i don't want to square the matrix, if I just need to square the elements of the diagonal?

Comment: Sorry for the previous comments (deleted). Those were wrong.Extremely sorry.

Comment: Take dot product of 1st row with 1st column to get (1,1) th entry of $A^2$. Similarly others.

Comment: I'm confused. Your method is not wrong? I'm just going to square the matrix and take the diagonal. When I get the $-3$ I take the roots (or factors of negative -3) and then from this, these are therefore the Eigenvalues?

Comment: My previous comments were wrong and confusing.I admit.I have deleted those and made a new comment. Extremely sorry again.

Comment: But can you please clarify what you want to know about the eigen values?Perhaps I have not understood your comment fully.Sorry

Comment: I have accepted this answer because it was clear and an elegant solution to my problem. I thank you once again. Basically, I'm trying to calculate the Eigenvalues of this matrix. So I was told that I can take the characteristic polynomial of the matrix and then calculate the roots of the polynomial and these are the eigenvalues?

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer.Yes,roots of characteristic polynomial are the eigen values of the matrix.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15121/discussion-between-user1326876-and-usermath).

Comment: I don't think this works.. For example: $A = \begin{bmatrix}
4 &6  &10 \\ 
3 & 10 &13 \\ 
2 & 6 &8  
\end{bmatrix}$ then the trace of this is: 22 and the trace of $A^2 = 412$ So therefore: $22 - 412 = -390$ where the answer should actually be: 36?

Comment: Please forget the last comment. I've figured it out. I wasn't ^2 it

Comment: Sorry..I was not here for a while.Thank you for your comments and nice to see that you have figured out the last problem in your comment. Thnx again.

Answer (score 2):

See [Wolfram Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CharacteristicPolynomial.html) for your formula. It notes that Einstein summation is used in the coefficient for $x$, so you have to sum over both $i$ and $j$ to get the actual answer.

The matlab answer gives the negative of $P_3(x)$ (as these have the same roots anyway): 1 stands for $x^3$, the -4 for the negative trace $1+2+1$, and the final $-1$ is just minus the determinant. So if you apply the formula with $-x^3$ at the start, we want the $x$-coefficient to be $3$, not $-3$.

So compute the missing coefficient as the double sum ${1 \over 2}\sum_{i=1}^3\sum_{j=1}^3 (a_{ij}a_{ji} - a_{ii}a_{jj})$.